# Return identity column values

Tags: python, sql-server

I have a some records(>1) which needed to be inserted into database and return the inserted records back into code(along with newly formed id in identity column). I need to make a call from python code to insert records into sql server.
I want to do all this in a single call to database. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When inserting multiple records into a table you can access the newly inserted data by using the OUTPUT clause in the INSERT statement. [MSDN Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx)

Here is some code to demonstrate:

```sql
/* Test table to demonstrate */
CREATE TABLE Test (ID INT IDENTITY(1, 1), Value VARCHAR(255));
GO
-- I'm using a table valued parameter to pass in the recordset
CREATE TYPE InputTable AS TABLE (Value VARCHAR(255));
GO

-- Test procedure to demonstrate
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.InsertTest
    @In InputTable READONLY -- Pass in a recordset to insert
AS 

SET NOCOUNT ON

-- Create a temp table to return the results
CREATE TABLE #Test (ID INT, Value VARCHAR(255));

-- Insert the data into the test table
INSERT INTO Test (Value)
OUTPUT inserted.ID, inserted.Value INTO #Test -- Output the newly inserted records including the new ID into the temp table
SELECT *
FROM @In;

-- Return the inserted data including the new ID
SELECT * FROM #Test;

DROP TABLE #Test;
GO

-- Declare a variable that references the input
DECLARE @Input AS InputTable;

-- Add data to the variable
INSERT INTO @Input (Value)
SELECT name
FROM sys.objects;

-- Execute the test procedure
EXEC InsertTest @Input;
GO

DROP TABLE Test;
DROP PROCEDURE InsertTest;
DROP TYPE InputTable;
```

Comment: the above is an sql stored procedure.
I'm trying to implement a method where it accepts the sql statement and values(list of lists) as input and return the inserted records along with created id's in python

Comment: That is just an example of how to use the OUTPUT statement. It doesn't have to be wrapped in a stored procedure.